# I want to pull Github pages to my hosting automatically after changes

Tags: node.js, github, jekyll, github-pages

I want that when i push changes from my local folder to github repository, then server automatically pull the changes from github repository. (My repository is currently private)

Actually this scenario is already configured on one of my client's server. (Hosting from [hahosting.com](https://hahosting.com/))

I'm using Jekyll to create a static blog like website for my client. Currently in his server previous developer setup auto pull from github repository but, i can't find any code or schedule task from that server which show how he did this (Its a windows server and its a shared hosting).

Current scenario:

1) Build Jekyll (building from gulp) -> save all code in `_site` directory

2) Push all directory with jekyll app code + `_site` directory.

3) Server auto pull changes within 15-20 mints automatically from `_site` 
directory in Github repository.

Comment: You could set up a webhook client for listening to GitHub pushes.

Comment: use some CI/CD tool like travis or circle CI?

Comment: Please don't offer to provide credentials to us. You shouldn't be so willing to give them to others, especially anonymous strangers. And nobody is going to log onto your server for you. The help you can get on SO needs to happen on SO, and questions should be self-contained.